# Printing text in the same line and calling sleep function

Tags: python-3.x, function, sleep

Here is my programming so far

```
import time

from time import sleep

print (print("narwhales");sleep[0.1],print("narwhales");sleep[0.1])
```

my wanted results are

**narwhales (a little bit later) narwhales**

Unfortunately, it just gives me an error. 
Please keep the explanation simple, I am very new to python3 and I don't know the all the words yet.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: File "main.py", line 3  
    print(print("narwhales");sleep[0.1],print("narwhales");sleep[0.1])
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
exited with non-zero status (its pointing at the ";")

Comment: Nested print-statements don't make sense. In addition, call sleep with sleep(0.1) instead of sleep[0.1].

Comment: im sorry, im new to python, what does nested mean?

Comment: nested means in this case something like print(print()). See my answer for a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 the following should work

```
from time import sleep
print('narwhales', end='', flush=True); sleep(1); print('narwhales')
```

First, the script prints `narwhales`on the screen. The parameter `end=''` means that not linebreak should occur. The parameter `flush=True` flushes the text to console immediatly. The script then waits 1 second and prints the second string. This time followed by a newline.

Also note that this could also be written like

```
from time import sleep
print('narwhales', end='', flush=True)
sleep(1)
print('narwhales')
```

Comment: @JOSHUASTRICKLAND if this solution answers your question feel free to 'accept' this answer and/or vote it up.